# error in could not find function in r with pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm just starting with r, so this may very well be a very simple question but...
I've tried changing the name in 'a' to be more elaborate but this makes no difference
If I try to assign it to a variable
(e.g. `baseline <- a %>% filter(Period == "Baseline") %>% group_by(File)%>%`

It just tells me:

> "Error in a %>% filter(Period == "Baseline") %>% group_by(File) %>%  :
> could not find function "%>%<-"

I'd really be grateful for any help with this.

It keeps telling me "Error in a(.) : could not find function "a"
and that it is unable to find Baseline_MAP even though it is defined earlier.
in mutate(Delta_MAP = Group_MAP - Baseline_MAP,

```
a <- read_csv("file.csv")
summary(a)

a %>%
  filter(Period == "Baseline") %>%
  group_by(File)%>%
  summarise(Baseline_MAP = mean(MAP_Mean, na.rm=T), 
            Baseline_SBP = mean(SBP_Mean, na.rm=T),
            Baseline_LaserMc1 = mean(Laser1_Magic, na.rm=T),
            Baseline_Laser1 = mean(Laser1_Mean, na.rm=T))%>%
  
a%>%
  filter(Period != "Baseline") %>%
  group_by(File)%>%
  summarise(Group_MAP = mean(MAP_Mean, na.rm=T),
            Group_SBP = mean(SBP_Mean, na.rm=T),
            Group_Laser_1Magic = mean(Laser1_Magic, na.rm=T),
            Group_Laser_1 = mean(Laser1_Mean, na.rm=T))
a%>% 
  mutate(Delta_MAP = Group_MAP - Baseline_MAP,
         Delta_MAP_Log = log(Group_MAP)-log(Baseline_MAP),
         Delta_SBP = Group_SBP - Baseline_SBP,
         Delta_SBP_Log = log(Group_SBP)-log(Baseline_SBP),
         Delta_Laser1_Magic = Group_Laser_1Magic - Baseline_LaserMc1,
         Delta_Laser1_Log = log(Group_Laser_1Magic)-log(Baseline_LaserMc1))
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! It would be best to include some sample data in your question post, so others can play with your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%>%` is from the package "dplyr". So make sure you load it, i.e. `library(dplyr)`.

Next, `%>%` does *not* assign the result to a variable. I.e.

a %>% mutate(foo=bar(x))

does *not* alter `a`. It will just show the result on the console (and none if you are running the script or calling it from a function).

You might be confusing the pipe-operator with `%<>%` (found in the package magrittr) which uses the left-hand variable as input for the pipe, and overwrites the variable with the modified result.

Finally, when you write

> If I try to assign it to a variable (e.g. `baseline <- a %>% filter(Period == "Baseline") %>% group_by(File)%>%`)

You are assigning the result from the pipeline to a variable `baseline` -- this however does not modify the variable-names in the data frames (i.e. the column names).